# How do I add a second function to a plugin in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts

I have this.

```
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options,
  plugins: [{
    id: "responsiveGradient",

    afterLayout: function(downChart) {
      console.log(downChart);
      let scales = downChart.scales;
      let color = downChart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, scales["x-axis-0"].top, 0, 0);

      //let chartColors = getChartColors(status);
      color.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0, 181, 63, 0.01)");
      color.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 181, 63, 0.6)");

      downChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = color;
    },
  }]
});
```

And i need to add a second function after the "afterLayout" key.

More information here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html

Comment: So you just need to run two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define and call the two functions you want to run when the afterLayout handler is called:

```
function func1(downChart) {
    console.log(downChart);
    let scales = downChart.scales;
    let color = downChart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, scales["x-axis-0"].top, 0, 0);

    //let chartColors = getChartColors(status);
    color.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0, 181, 63, 0.01)");
    color.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 181, 63, 0.6)");

    downChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = color;
};

function func2(downChart) {
    ....
};
```

Then within the anonymous function, you can call the two above.

```
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: options,
plugins: [{
    id: "responsiveGradient",

    afterLayout: function(downChart) {
        func1(downChart);
        func2(downChart);
      },
    }]
});
```

Comment: This was a really stupid question to ask. I actually had another problem, but thought this was the problem.

Comment: It's not obvious until it is :). Cheers!

Comment: Indeed, this helped me. Question and answer.